# Animation jumps to 0 position on all axes while using AnimationCurve on x

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I am currently studying animation creation on runtime. Here is my code snippet where I am moving my cube x position to 2.

```
anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
AnimationCurve translateX= null;
  
translateX = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, this.transform.position.x, 2f, 2f);
animationClip = new AnimationClip();
animationClip.legacy = true;
animationClip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", translateX);
anim.AddClip(animationClip, this.name);
anim.Play(this.name);
```

But the problem is every time I play my scene, my object position jumps to zero position.

Why it is happening? Like I am only animating the x position then, why are other axes changing?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for the animation system to control only one axis of the position (or the rotation, by the way). That's because the position is one single value of type Vector3. It can only be set completely.

But there is a workaround: Make the animated object the child of an empty game-object. Use the parent to control the world-position of the whole object. Now the animator only animates the *local* position, while the *global* position is controlled by the parent.

Comment: Oh! I suppose that it will work automatically and i am doing something wrong. Thanks for the help i wrote a solution according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change y and z axis then, you have to provide the same value of these axes. As @Philipp said we can not provide single axis in position or rotation.

```
animationClip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", translateX);
float defaultY = this.transform.position.y;
float defaultZ = this.transform.position.z;
animationClip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.y", AnimationCurve.Linear(0, defaultY, 2f, defaultY));
animationClip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.z", AnimationCurve.Linear(0, defaultZ, 2f, defaultZ));
```